# How to set value to a field in mongodb without using the field in view form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I want to set a value to Status property without using it in the view form

Here is the model class

```
public class NewsLetterModels
        {
            [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
            public string Id { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public string NewsLetterName { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "E-mail is not valid")]
            public string AssigneeEmailId { get; set; }

            public string Status { get; set; }

            public NewsLetterModels()
            {

            }

            public NewsLetterModels(PostNewsLetter postNewsLetter)
            {
                NewsLetterName = postNewsLetter.NewsLetterName;
                AssigneeEmailId = postNewsLetter.AssigneeEmailId;
                Status = postNewsLetter.Status;
            }

        }
```

I don't want to set value to the field in viewform.In fact I don't want to show this field in the viewform. when I click on initiate News Letter,"Initiated" value should be set to the propert "Status". I am using MongoDb as database

Here is the View Page

```
 <fieldset>
        <legend>PostNewsLetter</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewsLetterName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewsLetterName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewsLetterName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssigneeEmailId)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AssigneeEmailId)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssigneeEmailId)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Initiate NewsLetter" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the 'Status' property?
You should set this in the controller or if you are using a repository layer you could in a save method insert values before saving to database.